# how to add a string which consist extra percentage sign

Tags: objective-c

I ve got a string url where i need to append a string at the very end of the url.but the problem is there are extra percentage signs and getting warning "Format specifies double but the argument has of type NSString".how to solve this is issuse.
Below is the code

```
boxOfficeWeekly = [ServerApi getCollections:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.boxofficeindia.co.in/weekly-collections-%E2%80%93-box-office/%@",selectedPickerValue]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put just double `%%` symbol intead of single `%` symbol. And use this string

```
  boxOfficeWeekly = [ServerApi getCollections:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.boxofficeindia.co.in/weekly-collections-%%E2%%80%%93-box-office%@",selectedPickerValue]
```

Comment: By doing this .i was able to get rid of the warning..but its getting crashed.since the above is html feed url,adding an extra percent gives null feeds

Comment: I dont know about it. Might be other problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to double the % signs in nsstring to escape them if they are not a parameter like this %% or use the

```
- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

method for the first part of your string wich will automatically escape all % signs https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding

in your sample it would be something like this:

```
 Nsstring *url = [@"http://www.boxofficeindia.co.in/weekly-collections-%E2%80%93-box-office/" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 boxOfficeWeekly = [ServerApi getCollections:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@, url, selectedpickervalue]];
```

Comment: could u help me use the above funtionality on the code given..coz adding %% helps me get rid of the warning but crashes.since the url is a html feed url..adding an extra percentage returns nil

Comment: @user578386 i've edited my answer with an example, can you please try it out?